# Can I add (and show) a user photo(s) in LightDM?

Tags: 11.10, lightdm, users, photo

I am wondering if there is an option for adding and showing a user photo in LightDM ?

Comment: I'd love that feature, but I fear lightdm might be a little immature for that yet.  Hope I'm wrong.  Someone?

Comment: I haven't seen an easy option but light dm does have a greeter [API](http://people.ubuntu.com/~robert-ancell/lightdm/reference/lightdm-gobject-1-User-Accounts.html) , which mentions getting user profile pics. So it just takes someone to create a new greeter for lightdm.conf I think! Not found any myself yet other than [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8nm4NpaVXE&sns=em) .

Comment: Do you want to change the user photo that you see after a lock screen or provide one at the login screen?

Comment: Yes, I would like to see a photo (user account) at the login screen.

Comment: Did you solve your question?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/539371/add-account-picture-to-ubuntu-login-greeting-screen/539374#539374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure looks like it is possible:

http://www.geek.com/articles/chips/ubuntu-adopts-lightdm-login-screens-to-get-more-exciting-20110512/

No idea how, though.

Comment: Nice review (seems like mockup of LightDM featured features :) )

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: See my answer to similar question here http://askubuntu.com/a/354028/10963