# Add account picture to Ubuntu login/greeting screen

Tags: login

Is it possible to show your user/profile picture on the login/greeting screen in Ubuntu 14.04? I don't mean change the background image. Rather, I would like to add a small user/account picture that would appear alongside the username when signing in. Can this be done in Lightdm, GDM, or Ubuntu Tweak?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to change account profile picture?](http://askubuntu.com/q/310151/65926)

Comment: @EricCarvalho While GDM does show the profile picture, I don't think the default LightDM greeter does. Voting to leave open in hopes of an answer for LightDm.

Answer (score 3):

To add your account picture, type `User Accounts` in the dashboard. Click on the application and when it opens, select the account for which you want to change picture.
On the right hand side your user account details appear where you can change your picture by selecting one from your computer or by taking a picture with your camera.

The default `unity-greeter` on Ubuntu doesn't seem to be able to show your avatar on the login screen but it does show on the lock screen.

Install `lightdm-gtk-greeter` by typing on the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter`

Then edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf as root. 
To do that type on the terminal

`sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf`

Replace

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

by

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

and save the file.

Now select an image of your choice, and rename it as `.face` (without any extension) and place it in your home directory. Now reboot to see the changes.

Comment: Thanks but that's not exactly what I asked. I know how to change my user/account picture.  What I was asking is whether it is possible to have your user/account picture be displayed on the login/greeting screen. Anyone know a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Try out the edit

Comment: lightdm.conf.d folder is empty. what to do ?

Comment: What is the difference between the login screen and the lock screen?

Comment: There is no file to edit.  It will automatically chose your associated picture when you reboot.  Updated for 18.04